# Refreshing ViewModel and view after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a table with child rows (always one child per row) acting as details section. In this details section users will be able to see a log history, and will also have the ability to input a specific log. Upon inputting a new log and clicking on the "Add" button, the log history should update and show the newly added event.

I have the following AJAX call that will be used to add a log and should refresh the details section, triggered after clicking on the "Add" button mentioned above:

```
 $('#addLog').click(function () {
        formData = {
            logType: logType.value, // Parameter to add a new log
            logComments: logComments.value, // Parameter to add a new log
            agent: agent.value // Parameter to add a new log
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddLog", "AgentUser")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // Here I should refresh the the details section
                // and clear the logType and logCommands inputs
            }
        });
    });
```

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLog(string logType, string logComments, string agent, AgentUserValidatePhoneIndexViewModel vm)
{
    DoDbStuff();

    // Here I need to update the view model and view without having to
    // refresh the page, so that it shows the recently added event.

    return View(vm);
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class AgentUserValidatePhoneIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AgentUserWithoutValidPhone> AgentUserWithoutValidPhoneList { get; set; }
}
```

My Model:

```
public class AgentUserWithoutValidPhone
{
    private string phone;
    private DateTime creationDate;
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return phone;
        }
        set
        {
            phone = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().Parse("+" + value, String.Empty).NationalNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return creationDate;
        }
        set
        {
            creationDate = value;
            TimeSpan timeSpan = (DateTime.Now) - creationDate;
            TimeGoneBy = (timeSpan.Days != 0 ? timeSpan.Days + "d " : String.Empty) + timeSpan.Hours + "h";
        }
    }
    public string TimeGoneBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogEventDate { get; set; }
    public LogEventTypePhone LastLogEvent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AgentUsersLog> EventList { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach (var agentUser in Model.AgentUserWithoutValidPhoneList)
    {
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.Agent
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.Phone
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.CreationDate
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.TimeGoneBy
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.LastLogEventDate
            </td>
            <td>
                @agentUser.LastLogEvent.GetDescription()
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow" id="">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="details">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <input type="hidden" id="agent" value='@agentUser.Agent'>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DropDownList("LogEventTypePhone", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Enums.LogEventTypePhone)), "Select log event",
                                    new
                                    {
                                        id = "logType",
                                        @class = "form-control"
                                    })
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" id="logComments">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="addLog">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Event date</th>
                                <th>Event type</th>
                                <th>Comments</th>
                                <th>User</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var e in agentUser.EventList)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@e.Date</td>
                                    <td>@(((Enums.LogEventTypePhone)e.Subtype).GetDescription())</td>
                                    <td>@e.Comments</td>
                                    <td>@e.AspNetUsers.UserName</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

How do I pass my ViewModel into my controller action, together with the parameters? Right now it's empty by the time I get to the action. I need to pass it into the action, interact with the DB, update the ViewModel, return to the View and have it updated with the current ViewModel.

I've never done what I'm trying to do here and I'm confused about it. Not sure if it's even possible, or maybe I should use several ViewModels.

Comment: How does the markup for your add form and list of logs looks like ?

Comment: Could you try showing what your `AgentUserValidatePhoneIndexViewModel` code looks like?

Comment: You do not even need to return the updated full view model. at client side you can update the UI when your ajax call is a success.

Comment: @Shyju How do I do that?

Comment: We cannot tell you that without seeing how your markup looks like because it depends on your DOM structure. Show the relevant HTLM markup generated for one item in your table

Comment: I just added ViewModel, Model and View code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass the view model to the controller and back again (it would just unnecessarily degrade performance). If your just wanting to add a new row based on the values you post to your controller method, then create a anonymous object (or a new instance of `AgentUsersLog`) containing the values to be shown in the new row, return it as json and update the DOM by adding a new `<tr>` element.

There are a few other issues with you code including the fact your creating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) in your `foreach` loops. Remove the `id` attributes and use class names instead in conjunction with relative selectors (the code you have shown will only ever handle the `.click()` event of the first link with `id="addLog"`). You view code should be

```
@foreach (var agentUser in Model.AgentUserWithoutValidPhoneList)
{
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".details" class="accordion-toggle">
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse details"> // use class name
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" class="agent" value='@agentUser.Agent'> // must be inside a td element
                                @Html.DropDownList("LogEventTypePhone", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Enums.LogEventTypePhone)), "Select log event", new
                                {
                                    id = "", // remove id
                                    @class = "form-control logType" // add class name
                                })
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control logComments" placeholder="Comments"> // use class name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm addLog"> // use class name
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            ....
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var e in agentUser.EventList)
                        {
                            ....
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the script becomes

```
var url = '@Url.Action("AddLog", "AgentUser")';
$('.addLog').click(function () {
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    var logType = table.find('.logType').val();
    var logComments = table.find('.logComments').val();
    var agent = table.find('.agent').val();
    $.post(url, { logType: logType, logComments: logComments, agent: agent }, function(data) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        row.append($('<td></td>').text(data.Date));
        .... // add other cells for data.Subtype, data.Comments and data.UserName
        table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
});
```

Then in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddLog(string logType, string logComments, string agent)
{
    DoDbStuff();
    // Build the data to return
    var data = new
    {
      Date = .... ,
      Subtype = .... ,
      Comments = ..... ,
      UserName = ....
    };
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's invaluable. Thank you very much for helping me understand the proper way to do this, which I do now. However, after changing all the id's for classes, right now my details row doesn't expand after clicking on the parent row. How do I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, did not spot anything in your code relating to that. I cant see anything that's hidden (and needs to be expanded) so not sure which element your referring to.

Comment: OK, got it now. If its necessary to use an `id` in `data-target="someID"` then you just need to give the associated `<div>` a unique `id`. One way is you use a counter. Before the loop define `@{ int counter = 1; }` and then inside the loop - `var rowid = "details-" + counter++;` and make the html `<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@rowid" class="accordion-toggle">` and `<div class="accordian-body collapse" id="@rowid">`

Comment: I don't think is necessary to use an `id`, it's just that directly copying and pasting your code didn't work cause `data-target="#details"` should say `data-target=".details"` and `class="accordian-body collapse" class="details"` needs to be all together for it to work (it seems), as in `class="accordian-body collapse details"`. I had to change these in all the other examples but `logType`, which you put in the same class statement. Can you edit your answer with this changes so that it works out of the box? I'll select it as correct then.

Comment: That was just me being lazy and not checking what I wrote :). Have updated now (think I got them all)

Comment: And as a side note, its probably not even necessary to return all the data I have show, for example if `logComments` that you send to the controller is the same as `Comments = ..... ,`, then you already know what it is in the view so you can just use `row.append($('<td></td>').text(logComments));`. You will also want to consider what happens if there is an error on the server.

Comment: That makes sense, although `logComments` is the only case in which I can do that. How would you go about the error handling?

Comment: Easy way is catch any exception in the controller and if so, `return Json(null);` and then the script would be `$.post(url, ....., function(data) { if(data) { // add the row } else { // display an error message or alert } });` but you can also return specific HttpErrors and handle then in `$.post(... { ... }).fail(function(data) { // do something based on the error });`

Comment: I'm taking notes. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by creating child object. Lets assume the model "AgentUserValidatePhoneIndexViewModel" has the below properties

1. Phone (int)
2. AgentDetail (string)

then generate formData as follows

```
formData = {
            logType: logType.value, // Parameter to add a new log
            logComments: logComments.value, // Parameter to add a new log
            agent: agent.value // Parameter to add a new log
            vm : { // Parameter to add values to view model
               phone : answer.value,
               agentDetail : agentDetail.value
            }
        }
```

Check this post to know how to render partial views

This post explains https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: That would allow me getting date from the ViewModel. What I want is UPDATE the data in the ViewModel and send it back to the View so that the user can see the changes in real time.

Comment: Then you need to use two way binding (Libraries like knockout) or manually assign the values to the view in Ajax success method.